# Variable dependency...easy one

Tags: differential-equations, variable-definitions, assignment

I'm brand new to Mathematica...should be an easy one. Instead of writing u[x] everywhere in the code, how do I assign the dependency early on like this:

```
u=u[x]
```

so that instead of writing this everywhere

```
D[u[x],x]
```

I can just write

```
D[u,x]
```

This is just a simple example but I find it annoying to have to bracket all the dependent variables all the time.

Comment: Give it a different name. Try `f = u[x]` and `D[f, x]` instead. Not really sure that I recommend doing things that way, but it works for your expressions.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing now which works, but then I have all these dummy names and it's a little harder to keep track of. Why would you not recommend doing it this way? This seems like a trivial issue. Why would you not be able to assign variable dependency? It makes the code very messy for no apparent reason.

Comment: You can answer your question yourself by trying to execute `u = u[x]`.

Comment: @ Guess who: Don't you think I would have tried that already? Hence why I'm asking the question.

Comment: You can do it in Matlab...thought you could do it in Mathematica. I guess it's not possible?

Comment: Right, and what error did you happen to see? (Look, I'm trying to impart something; just go along.)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. That depends on what he's actually doing and in what order  `ClearAll[u];
u[x_] := Sin[x];
u = u[x];
D[u, x]`

Comment: @bel, fair point, but to me that is a far more confusing state of affairs.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Agree. My point is that the outcome depends on what you're actually doing after your last `Clear` and in what order. That may surely confuse a new user

Comment: Wow...I think it's just not possible, otherwise it would have been a simple answer. Say U[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k], in other words it has a lot of dependent variables. If I want to take the partial derivative with respect to "a", I have to write D[U[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k],a] every time. If I could predefine the dependency, I could just write D[U,a]. It's 10x cleaner. That is all I'm asking. The function for U is not known...I'm doing vector calculus so there are a lot of derivatives.

Comment: Am I totally losing you in what I'm asking?

Comment: If the right answer is "no, you have to write out the dependency every time" then that's fine

Comment: u[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := a^2 + b^3 - c^2 + d*e;
uvars = {a, b, c, d, e};
D[u @@ uvars, uvars[[2]]] or
D[u @@ uvars, b]...etc.

Comment: This will work in the specific case you gave: `uvars=Sequence[a,b,c,d,e,f]; fn[uvars]=a^2+3b+4c+2d; D[fn[uvars],b]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've seen, a definition like

```
u = u[x,y,z]
```

is not generally appropriate in *Mathematica* because the [principle of the *Mathematica* evaluator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html) is to repeatedly apply all known definitions to an expression until the result no longer changes. Here, the recursive definition is repeatedly applied, with no termination condition.

If you're just looking for a shorthand notation for `u[x,y,z]`, a simple way to define one would be

```
u[] = u[x,y,z]
```

which sidesteps the recursion issue. (It defines a downvalue for `u`, rather than an ownvalue.) Now you can do

```
D[u[], x]
```

> $u^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z)$

Matlab has a whole "symbolic function" apparatus that doesn't exist in *Mathematica*, because it's unecessary -- any expression can act as a symbolic function. However, we can set up a similar behavior if we want. One possible way is to preprocess all input to add the arguments to bare function calls.

Set it up with

```
$SymbolicFunctions = {};
DeclareSymbolicFunction[func_[var__]] := AppendTo[$SymbolicFunctions, func[var]];
ClearSymbolicFunctions[] := $SymbolicFunctions = {};
SetAttributes[replaceSymbFuncs, HoldAll];
replaceSymbFuncs[input_] := Unevaluated@input /. 
    Flatten[{#[[0]][v__] -> #[[0]][v], #[[0]] -> #} & /@ $SymbolicFunctions];
$Pre = replaceSymbFuncs;
```

Now we can declare a symbolic function

```
DeclareSymbolicFunction[u[x, y, z]]
```

If we call the function with no arguments, the arguments are appended

```
u
```

> $u(x,y,z)$

but if we call with different arguments, those are respected:

```
u[a, b, c]
```

> $u(a,b,c)$

And it works inside `D`, for example:

```
D[u^2, x]
```

> $2 u(x,y,z) u^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z)$