# Removing function arguments from expressions with derivatives

Tags: symbolic, formatting

( This question is basically the opposite of this one: [Variable dependency...easy one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87890/46327) )

I would like to be able to output expressions in Mathematica that look more like pen-and-paper math. In particular I want to have derivatives of functions without displaying the function arguments. Here is an example: the simple expression (let's use a Euclidean metric in both indices, where $\phi_i$ is a complex-valued function on the variables $(t,x,y,z)$ )

$$\partial^\mu \phi^i \partial_\mu \phi_i$$

becomes in Mathematica

$$\left(\phi (1)^{(0,0,0,1)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (2)^{(0,0,0,1)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (3)^{(0,0,0,1)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (1)^{(0,0,1,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (2)^{(0,0,1,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (3)^{(0,0,1,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (1)^{(0,1,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (2)^{(0,1,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (3)^{(0,1,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (1)^{(1,0,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi
   (2)^{(1,0,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2+\left(\phi (3)^{(1,0,0,0)}(t,x,y,z)\right)^2$$

(here is the code:

```
\[Phi]Vec = {\[Phi][1][t, x, y, z], \[Phi][2][t, x, y, z], \[Phi][3][
   t, x, y, z]};

expr = Sum[
 Table[Inactive[D][\[Phi]Vec[[i]], \[Mu]], {\[Mu], {t, x, y, z}}] . 
  Table[Inactive[D][\[Phi]Vec[[i]], \[Mu]], {\[Mu], {t, x, y, z}}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

)

The number of terms aside, the visual noise of all the arguments quickly becomes totally untenable. Absent the use of a complicated package, what strategies can we employ to remove the function arguments?

Here is my attempt. It is not a good general strategy because inactive derivatives in the definition of `expr` will get in the way of algebraic simplification. Here there is no simplification that needs to be done so it works anyway.

```
Block[{\[Phi]},
 \[Phi][n_][x___] := \[Phi][n];
 expr;
 % /. \[Phi][i_] -> Subscript[\[Phi], i]
 ]
```

The expression becomes

$$\left(\frac{\partial \phi _1}{\partial t}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi
   _2}{\partial t}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _3}{\partial
   t}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _1}{\partial
   x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _2}{\partial
   x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _3}{\partial
   x}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _1}{\partial
   y}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _2}{\partial
   y}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _3}{\partial
   y}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _1}{\partial
   z}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _2}{\partial
   z}\right){}^2+\left(\frac{\partial \phi _3}{\partial z}\right){}^2$$

Comment: Algebraic simplification/collection aside, you might like giving definitions to `Format`. For example, evaluating `Format[\[Phi][n_][t_, x_, y_, z_]] := Subscript[\[Phi], n]` causes `expr` to automatically render as the "cleaned up" version

Comment: @thorimur Thanks, `Format` is new to me and looks very useful indeed!